# block nginx connection after multiple 404 s on same tcp connection

Tags: nginx, security, fail2ban

I'd like to protect two servers against attackers who blindly probe for urls.

my idea is to block requests after a certain amount of 404 status codes.

I could do this with fail2ban.

However one of the servers is behind a reverse proxy **that I do not control**  and that **does not communicate the originating IP address** (and it will need a very long time before the request of forwarding the originating IP address will be handled), meaning that **from nginx's point of few all requests originate from the revere proxy's IP** and obviously I don't want to block all incoming traffic if somebody provokes too many 404s.

Is there any way (without fail2ban, with fail2ban or with any other tool)
to detect at least 404 errors **from the same https connection** and to terminate this connection or to let it 404 unconditionally for any subsequent request?

Please tell me if my question is not clear and I'll try to rephrase it, to give more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Nginx to cache responses, including responses with an error such as a 404. However, as far as I know, you cannot count the number of errors (but that shouldn't matter).

The only issue here is that if you create a new page and earlier it was cached as a 404, then it won't work. At least, not immediately (depending on how long your cache takes to timeout).

That will definitely help greatly, though. All the hits that would otherwise go to your backend and generate a 404 will be stopped at the Nginx instance and return the exact same 404 error over and over again.

Another way, is to define a location and run a command (which could then run `ipset` to add the IP address). So something like:

```
location /phpmyadmin.php {
  content_by_lua_block {
    os.execute("/usr/bin/block-ip.sh")
  } 
}
```

I'm not too sure how you could handle many paths, however.

---

My own experience with `fail2ban` is that it's rather slow and "backward" (not proactive). If you really want to completely block an IP address, though, the easiest is to have your app. send a message to the front end where you can run `iptables` to block the IP. For that you need to forward the original IP which Nginx doesn't do by default, but it's easy to add an `X-Forwarded-For` header that your app. can then send back to the small tool you're using to add IPs to your `iptables`. Note also you should not directly add it to `iptables`. Instead you should use a list. For that look at the `ipset`.

If you can't change your apps for such and want to use `fail2ban`, you'd have to check the Nginx logs and detect those paths you do not like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

yep caching 404 s might reduce DOS attacks if multiple attackers were scanning a server within the cache age;

However what I really would prefer is to stop somebody who's trying to guess urls.

And on servers where I can't do it due to absence of the originating IP address I would like at least to avoid, that one SSL connection can probe for too many urls

Out of curiousity:
What would be the setup to cache 404 errors?
The caching had to be server side as I want to mitigate attacks by bots and not attacks from a browser.

Comment: @gelonida Thinking about it, you can run a shell command from Nginx, so could use that to block the IP immediately (you may still get 2 or 3 more hits, but that will be really fast). To make it fast, make sure to use a rule pointing to a list of IPs managed by `ipset`.

Comment: thanks for your updated answer. I'm still not sure how it helps in my current case.

Probably I have to wait until the reverse proxy will have the X-Forwarded-For header added, but then I still have to see how to block requests (Please see a related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1094926/can-fail2ban-add-deny-rules-to-nginx-instead-of-using-iptables )

Answer (score 0):

Nginx has a `limit_req` module, so you can use it as pre-filtering.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877242/nginx-limit-req-based-on-http-header for similar question.

For instance by counting and limiting the 404 attempts (e. g. in related error location) and/or filter them by fail2ban hereafter if you'd log only limited requests.
This way you could decrease `maxretry` and `findtime` for the jail in fail2ban and can avoid too high load by lot of messages in log (see [fail2ban :: wiki / Best-practice](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic)).

For the filter example (basically you don't need the filter you can simply set `failregex` etc directly in jail), see [filter.d/nginx-limit-req.conf](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/nginx-limit-req.conf). You can also configure nginx to log `X-Forwarded-For` header instead or additionally to the real IP. And even ban both of them using different `maxretry`/`findtime` combined with different limits and bursts in `limit_req` module.

Comment: I changed the title and highlighted some parts of my message.

In fact the main problem is I want to detect 404's on the same http connection.
I am afraid it will need a lot of time before the reverse proxy will be changed and provide me the information. that I really need.